# Create MSI that behaves like ClickOnce

Tags: windows-installer, clickonce

Not the auto-update part, but the part that allows a piece of software to be installed and used without requiring being or becoming an admin. So in other words - are there conditions under which an MSI would NOT require elevation and install the software with the same security sandbox offered by ClickOnce.

Comment: Off topic suggestion; but if you aren't tied to an MSI, Paul Betts made [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) which I would recommend.

Comment: IMO auto-updating is the only upside to click once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can author an MSI that installs per-user and only writes to areas the user has access to.  HCKU instead of HKLM,  user profile instead of ProgramFiles and so on.   But you will not have a "sandbox" like ClickOnce and to be honest these types of installers are a pain to service and enterprises don't like them.

Comment: I suspected so, thank you for confirming. I guess I'll have to go through the publishing through policy route...